# How to deploy a chat client made in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, html, deployment, socket.io, node-webkit

I have made a chat client with socket.io and express.Now i want to deploy it as a desktop app.I mention i dont want to use heroku.I generally use node-webkit to deploy apps so how do i use it in this case.
The app starts with command     "start": "node app.js".
Please Help.

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: i have made the app.It works at localhost:3000.Now i want to deploy it but i dont know how to deploy it with websockets.

Comment: Do deploy it, try it out and then share your problem along with your relevant code if any...

Comment: sorry i couldnt explain

Comment: i have found out a solution i will first deploy it on my github.io and then redirect the app to the page.

Comment: thanks for the help rayn